# Invalidate Flask session?

Tags: python, json, session, flask

I'm testing JSON based login/logout functionality with httpie (https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#sessions).
The problem I have is that once I login no matter how many times I "logout" I can not clean up the session.
On the logout I can see clearly that the session is cleared, but when I call "status" afterwards the session 
content is preserved (still there) ???

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? How to invalidate the Session on logout ?

here is the code :

```
http  -v --session=log3 -j :5000/start/status
http  -v --session=log3 -j :5000/start/logout
http  -v --session=log3 -j :5000/start/status



@start.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
def logout():
    print session
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    session.clear()
    print session
    return jsonify({'rv' : 'ok' })

@start.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
  print session
  if 'logged_in' in session and session['logged_in'] :       
     return jsonify({'status' : True })
  return jsonify({'status' : False})
```

Comment: Is your Ajax call not updating the client cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it .... didn't know that by default Flask uses client-side sessions !?!!? whaaat !!

Once you install Flask-Session instead everything is fine !
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/